# mysql having and aggregate functions

Tags: mysql

I'm tryng to get all "balcao" with max. values of "nCli" with

```
SELECT cli.idBalcao, count(*) AS nCLientes
  FROM cliente AS cli
  GROUP BY cli.idBalcao
  HAVING nClientes=MAX(nClientes)
```

Anyone knows why that doesn't work?
I solved it using a user defined variable, but this code should work on MySQL.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

What if you change that to

```
SELECT cli.idBalcao, count(*) AS nCLientes,
MAX(nCli) as maxClientes
  FROM cliente AS cli
  GROUP BY cli.idBalcao
  HAVING nClientes = maxClientes
```

(OR)

```
SELECT cli.idBalcao, count(*) AS nCLientes
  FROM cliente AS cli
  GROUP BY cli.idBalcao
  HAVING nClientes IN (select MAX(nCli) from cliente)
```

Comment: MAX(nClientes)? Sunstroke?

Comment: It's not really getting any better :-(

Comment: Unfortunately none of these work, but I was able to solve it with a view (a little better than the user variable). Your second option doesn't work because nCli is not a column in table cliente. But I still don't know why my original code does not work. Any ideas?